# Find an orthogonal matrix Q that diagonalizes this symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, orthogonality, symmetric-matrices

$$\begin {bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&-1&-2\\2&-2&0\end{bmatrix}$$

computing the eigenvalues gives me $$\lambda=0$$ $$\lambda=3$$ $$\lambda=-3$$

my probles are finding the eigenvectors.  computing  the eigenvectors gives me

$$\begin {bmatrix}-2\\-2\\-1 \end{bmatrix}$$ $$\begin {bmatrix}1\\-1/2\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

the first two eigenvectors are not the books answers

Comment: Have you tried normalizing your vectors? (i.e. $w=v/|v|$)

Comment: the book is introduction to linear algebra by gilbert Strang problem set 6.4 5 excercise

Comment: yes but the lengh of the second vector is different from the first one

Comment: in the book the 3 eigenvectors are the same lenght

Comment: Did you try to follow @HoldenRohrer 's suggestion? Try scaling each of your vectors down by their length to get unit vectors (length = $1$)

Comment: already try that

Comment: you guys have the book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenvectors of the matrix above are:

$$\vec{u_1} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\vec{u_2} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\vec{u_3} = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Those vectors are orthogonal, because of the Theorem that states that eigenvectos associated to different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

Now those eigenvectors form an orthogonal Base, but we must turn it into an orthonormal base. So we normalise the vectors dividing them by their norm:

$$\vec{n_1} = \dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\vec{n_2} = \dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\vec{n_3} = \dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

From this you can get the orthogonal matrix you want:

$$T = \begin{pmatrix}-\dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} & -\dfrac{2}{3} \\ \dfrac{2}{3} & -\dfrac{1}{3} & -\dfrac{2}{3} \\ \dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}$$

Or you can factorize $\dfrac{1}{3}$ outsie the matrix.

Comment: how do you compute the eigenvectors?

Comment: I try gauss eliminations but get different answers

Comment: Eigenvectors are found by solving the eigenvectors equation: $$(M - \lambda_k \mathbb{1})\vec{x}^t = \vec{0}$$

Where $M$ is your matrix, $\lambda_k$ is the $k-$th eigenvalue and $\vec{0}$ is the null vector.

Comment: can you elaborate on the procces of finding the nullspace  what method did you use?

Comment: For example, for $\lambda_1 = 0$ you have

$$M\vec{x} = \vec{0}$$ that is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 & -2 \\ 2 & -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then solve the associated homogeneous system, and find the base vector.

Comment: For example again, taking my previous comment, the space equations read:
$$\begin{cases}
x + 2z = 0 \\
-y - 2z = 0 \\
2x - 2y = 0
\end{cases}
$$

And from here you can easily get: $x = y$ and $y = -2z$ so you can write in function of $z$ as the vector $(-2z, -2z, z)$ that means $(-2, -2, 1)$ which is the third I wrote in the answer. The same with other eigenvalues.

Comment: what is the function of z ?

Comment: @ramanujansalkhazarim For every value fo $z$ you get a "different" (actually, proportional) eigenvector to the one you find by putting $z = 1$. When indeed $z = 1$ you get the "standard" eigenvector, or the generator. We always put $z = 1$ for every other value ($0$ is forbidden) gives you only a multiple of the generator, which is not useful per se.

Comment: thank you Kurt you are a legend

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ is symmetric so orthogonally diagonalizable, so the eigenvectors they are independent linearly, so orthogonal vectors. Hence only, we need to find the eigenvectors $v_{i}$ and then normalize $v_{i}/\|v_{i}\|$.

The eigenvalues are given solving $(A-\lambda I)=0$ and we have
$$\lambda_{1}=-3,\quad \lambda_{2}=3,\quad \lambda_{3}=0$$
The eigenvectors they are the solutions of the homogeneous system $(A-\lambda_{i})v=0$. I will find the first eigenvector, you can then mimic the process.

Setting $\lambda_{1}=-3$, we have
$$(A-(-3)I)v=0\iff \begin{bmatrix}1+3&0&2\\0&-1+3&-2\\2&-2&0+3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Using Row-Reductioj we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}1+3&0&2\\0&-1+3&-2\\2&-2&0+3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}1&0&1/2\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
So the eigenspace for $\lambda_{1}=-3$ is given by
$$E_{\lambda_{1}=-3}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\in {\bf R}^{3}: x=-t/2, y=t,z=t, t\in{\bf R}\right\}={\rm span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$Similarly we the others vectors. Finally you arrived for the set of eigenvectors given by $$S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1/2\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$
or re-scaling the vectors as $v_{1}=(-1,2,2), v_{2}=(-2,-2,1)$ and $ 
v_3=(2,-1,2)$, respectively.

The next step is find the normalizing with $u_{i}=v_{i}/\|v_{i}\|$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Finally, locate each $u_i$ in column and that is your orthogonal matrix $Q$.

Comment: It seems that I did not write fast enough, anyway I have posted my writing so that the effort is not in vain.

Comment: what do you mean by reescaling the vectors?

Comment: Multiply by a scalar different of zero a vector. On the other hand you shouldn't change the check of the answer given by Kurt Godel which is perfectly well explained and he tried his best to answer your questions in the comments.

Comment: you guys are legends